# How to send mail in Lotus Notes 8.5 with Embedded code

Tags: lotus-notes, embedded, code

Anyone can tell me please : How to send mail in Lotus Notes 8.5 with Embedded code ?

I tested with embedded youtube video, and it doesen't work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why doesn't it work? What do you expect it to do and what does it do?

Comment: When the sent mail is open, we see code instead of the content

Comment: Show us your code, then we probably can tell what you do wrong